# Fluid or Fixed layout for a social networking web application?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Folks,

Most of the examples I saw including facebook, twitter and orkut uses a fixed width pattern. It seems to be so easy for development and gives more control to move on. Fluidity screws up the views sometimes.

Why fluidity is more complex? Is it because, browsers are not matured enough?

What is the best way (in terms of visual elements) to do a web application? Pour me some thoughts!

Comment: You might have better luck [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Noufal Should I post the same question there?

Comment: @Noufal - Will do.. How do I close this thread here?

Comment: Just leave it. People *might* answer here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making fluid designs is more difficult for a number of reasons, hence a lot of sites don't bother with it to start with. When things get more involved, it's hard to add it afterwards.

Browsers can use media-queries, as well as max and min widths to design in this way, and good designers will do that from the start.

One of the harder things is that you can end up serving large images to mobile users unless you have multiple sizes of your images – this means that for a fluid site to be efficient you need to reencode resources at various sizes. This alone is enough to put people off.

Comment: Thats a good response. Are there any suggestions to follow as to start with fixed layout and to move towards fluid layout slowly?

Comment: The thing is that often things don't make sense when they are fluid – I'm doing a site right now with an image gallery with 4 images per row. If I make it fluid then I could also have 3 and 5 per row, but the spacing will look rubbish when it's almost 5 or almost 3. It's better to have 3 fixed layouts in my opinion there. Text looks bad as well if the line lengths are too big. I reckon a fixed number of fixed views is probably better.

Comment: Agree.. How about managing everything in percentages? So as it just zooms when the resolution is higher! Is this complex? Or it does not make sense at all?

Comment: Font size doesn't work like that, so you can't just zoom everything nicely. You could by using JS, but that seems a lot of overhead (repaint everything on any window resizing).

Comment: Cool.. Thanks Rich Bradshaw.. I'm clear! But, seems this question is something that shouldn't be here..

Comment: If you are asking in a technical way, with a view to implementing it then it's fine IMO. If you are just wondering why, then it's not.

Comment: This is to start implementing in the future things I do. Because I was so crazy about the liquid layout and was doing it quite a few days. This had issues in terms of resolution changes. I was confused and came here to ask them.. Purely technical! :-)